# Show that there exists a homeomorphism between $$ and the singleton sets in Closed$()$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Let $$ be a compact Hausdorff space. I want to show that there exists a homeomorphism between $$ and the subspace of Closed$()$ which is a set of singleton sets.

Where I need to start with a function given by sing$:\rightarrow\text{Cts}(,\Sigma)$ such that $\mapsto\chi_{\{\}}^$ where $\chi$ is the characteristic function and sing is continuous.

I have proved that there exists a homeomorphism such that Cts$(,\Sigma)\cong$ Open$()\cong$ Closed$()$ such that I can define a function $$ which is the composite of those homeomorphisms.

I have defined a continuous inverse mapping $:\{\{\}|∈\}→$ with $\{\}\mapsto $. $$ is obviously the inverse function but I want to show it is continuous.

Note that Closed($$) has the basis $\{\{\text{ closed in }|⊆\}\}$ where $$ is open in $$ and $^$ compact (which is automatically true as $^$ closed in compact $$).

Attempt: I have deduced that $^{−1}()=\{\{\}∈ \text{singleton of Close}()|∈\} = \{\{y\} \text{ closed in }Y|\{y\}\subseteq U\}$. And the subspace topology gives the fact that $\{\{\text{ closed in }|⊆\}\} \cap \{\{y\}|y\in Y\} = \{\{y\}|\{y\}\subseteq U\}$ hence $g$ is continuous. Am I correct? Thanks!

Comment: Please don't delete and re-post, rather you can edit.

Comment: @0-thUser sorry, didn't mean to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discarding the weird notations and putting it in terms familiar to me:

You have a hyperspace of closed sets (which I usually call $H(Y)$) with a base all sets $U^+ = \{A \in H(Y)\mid A \subseteq U\}$ where we restrict to $U$ that are open and have compact complement in $Y$ (so half of the Fell topology)
This is somewhat non-standard (I'm used to the Vietoris topology or the Fell topology), but seems to work for this question.

So $Y$ being Hausdorff and compact (just $T_1$ suffices), the map $i:Y \to H(Y); y \to \{y\}$ is well-defined.

It is continuous as $$i^{-1}[U^+] = \{y \in Y: \{y\} \subseteq U \} = U$$
for all basic open sets.

As $i$ is clearly injective and $i[U]=U^+ \cap i[Y]$ as well, $i$ is open as a map (any open $U \subseteq Y$ qualifies for usage as a base element as you already noted) from $Y$ onto $i[Y]$ and thus $Y \simeq i[Y]$ (and $i[Y]$ is the subspace if all singleton sets).

All other considerations are unneeded and just distract from the matter.